# there is few mistake in trigger help me to solve that problem

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

**Create trigger that will
not allow update of salary for employee
who are in sales department.**
Emp(no,name,dno,salary,designamtion)
Dept(dno,name,location)

Errors: TRIGGER MYTRIGGER1
Line/Col: 6/11 PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.EMP'
Line/Col: 6/31 PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.EMP'

```
DROP TABLE EMP;
DROP TABLE DEPT;
CREATE TABLE Dept
(
    dno NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(15),
    location VARCHAR(15)  );
CREATE TABLE Emp
(
    no NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(15),
    dno NUMBER,
    salary NUMBER,
    designamtion VARCHAR(15),
    FOREIGN KEY(dno) REFERENCES Dept(dno)  );

insert into DEPT values (1,'SALES','GUJARAT');
insert into DEPT values (2,'MARKETING','UP');
insert into DEPT values (3,'MANUFACTURING','MP');
insert into DEPT values (4,'DEALING','VAPI');
insert into DEPT values (5,'SELL','TAPI');

insert into EMP values (1,'AMAN',2,45400,'MANAGER');
insert into EMP values (2,'BHAMAN',5,20000,'GM');
insert into EMP values (3,'CHAMAN',3,34400,'ADVISOR');
insert into EMP values (4,'DAMAN',4,75400,'WORKER');
insert into EMP values (5,'KHAMAN',1,42400,'MANAGER');


CREATE OR REPLACE trigger MYTRIGGER1
BEFORE UPDATE OF SALARY ON EMP
for each row
declare
    hmmm VARCHAR(15);
begin
    select Dept.name into hmmm 
    from Dept, Emp
    where :old.emp.no=no and  :old.emp.dno=Dept.dno;
    dbms_output.put_line(hmmm);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to alias the table the trigger is on. This will compile fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger MYTRIGGER1
BEFORE UPDATE OF SALARY ON EMP
for each row
declare
    hmmm VARCHAR(15);
begin
    select Dept.name into hmmm 
    from Dept, Emp
    where :old.no=no and  :old.dno=Dept.dno;
    dbms_output.put_line(hmmm);
end;
```

However, this trigger will fail when you update the table. You cannot select from the table itself in the trigger body. This will raise a mutating table error. Since it is an assignment I'll leave the research up to you.

Answer (score 0):

As Koen said, your code will suffer from mutating table error.

Lucky you - you don't have to **select** from the table you're just updating (the `emp` table, right?) - you have everything you need in `:new.dno`. So:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger mytrigger1
  2    before update of salary on emp
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    hmmm varchar2(15);
  6  begin
  7    select d.name
  8      into hmmm
  9      from dept d
 10      where d.dno = :new.dno;
 11
 12    dbms_output.put_line('Department name = ' || hmmm);
 13  end;
 14  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> update emp set salary = 1000 where no = 1;
Department name = MARKETING

1 row updated.

SQL> update emp set salary = 1000;
Department name = MARKETING
Department name = SELL
Department name = MANUFACTURING
Department name = DEALING
Department name = SALES

5 rows updated.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request is a trigger that disallows certain action for employees in Sales. Your trigger would not do so even it compiled. Two problems:

1. dbms_output does not prevent anything it merely 'prints' a message.
2. it prevents any update to salary, except when emp.dno or emp.no is also updated.

First (getting up on soapbox). You are enforcing a business rule. This should not be done in a trigger. It should be done in either the business rules engine of your application or in a database constraint or if you want to be super cautions both. Now a trigger will do the enforcement but business rule violations should glaringly obvious and easy to find, in a trigger becomes a side effect of an action, hidden away and difficult to find. (OK enough of that getting off soapbox).  

The prevention method your looking for is [raise_application_error](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/error-management). And you want a little code as possible in a trigger. In this case you have everything needed from the EMP table through the pesudo rows :old and :new so there is no reason to join your tables. However you do need to look at the specific department. It is too bad Oracle constrains the Exists predicate to introduction of a sub-select, this would be a perfect place for the structure:

```
If EXISTS (selects ...) then ...
```

But that is not available. The following uses a technique of reversing the requirement. That is it selects what is NOT wanted then if found it raise the exception, and if not found it suppress the Oracle raised error. So:

```
create or replace trigger mytrigger1
   before update of salary on emp
   for each row
declare
   hmmm  varchar2(01);   
begin
    select null
      into hmmm
      from dept d   
     where d.dno = :old.dno
       and d.name = 'SALES';
     
     raise_application_error(-20199, 'Can not update salary for Employee in Sales.');
exception 
    when no_data_found then null;
end mytrigger1;
```

This is sometimes referred to as "Programming the Exception" and is not a generally recommended procedure but at times it is useful. See [fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aef7c556684da1496f55170c6934ea8a).
There is an outstanding question not addressed here. Can an employee in Sales have a salary change if they are also transferring departments. I.e. should the following succeed or fail?

```
update emp e
   set dno = 2
     , salary = salary + 5000
 where e.no = 5;
```